# Need suggestion for set date format using oracle report desformat for excel report

Tags: oracle, date-formatting, oraclereports

I have a oracle report which is to display a set of values and it can be generated both as pdf and csv formats. 
Excel doesnt consider the trainling zeros,so i tried the following way.

```
       IF :DESFORMAT='SPREADSHEET' THEN
               :CP_2:= '="'||:cmdt_grp_cd||'"';
       ELSE
               :CP_2:=:cmdt_grp_cd;
       END IF;
```

in the same how to set date values kindly suggest me?

Comment: Consider accepting answers to your previous questions first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030316/internal-functionality-of-dual-table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the [DATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATE-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) like this:

```
:CP_2:= '=DATE('||TO_CHAR(:cmdt_grp_cd, 'YYYY;MM;DD')||')';
```

Problem is, the separator can be `,` or `;` (or anything else actually) depending on your local windows settings.

I found this one https://superuser.com/a/686415, however I did not test it.

Comment: thank U,Wernfriend ,its working ,but in the output  m getting '/' ,then how to get dot(.) like 2012.12.12 kindly suggest me

Comment: Is `cmdt_grp_cd` a string data type?

Comment: its date datatype ,the result is comming 24/11/2015, but i need 24.11.2015 kindly suggest me

Comment: Ah, you mean the display format in Excel. No idea, I assume this depends on the local PC settings.